# Login with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I have a problem with a simple login with ajax, apparently all is right, but I don´t know what is wrong, because I need to send a message to the client indicating that the user info is right and then redirect to main page.

Source Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=<? echo APP_CHARSET ?>' />
        <title>Red Social Basica</title>
        <? Tag::css('reset') ?>
        <? Tag::css('design') ?>
        <? echo Html::includeCss() ?>
        <? echo Tag::js('jquery/jquery.min') ?>
    </head>
    <body class="fondobody">

        <header class="topbar">
            <a href="" class="bntesatico" id="lnklogin">Login</a>
            <div id="dvlogeo">
                  User/Email<input type="text" id="txtusremail"/>
                  Password<input type="password" id="txtpassword"/>
                  <a href="" id="lnkenter">Enter</a>
            </div> 
            <a href="" class="bntesatico" id="lnkregistro">Sign up</a>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#lnklogin').click(function() {
            $('#dvlogeo').fadeToggle(200, function() {
                var divID = $('#dvlistipopubs');
                var openDiv = $(this).is(':visible') ? divID : null;
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#lnkenter').click(function() {
            var usremail=$('#txtusremail').val(),
                password=$('#txtpassword').val();
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "account/login.php",
                    data: 'usremail=' + usremail +
                          '&password=' + password,
                    success: function(data) {
                       if(data=='ok'){
                           document.location="account/main.php"
                       }else{
                           alert('Access denied');
                       }
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
     });
    </script>
```

I used firebug to verify the answer from the server and is printing 'ok' if user and password are right and error if something is wrong, the problem is that is not working here

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data=='ok'){
        document.location="account/main.php"
    }else{
        alert('Access denied');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your php file?

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` returns?, before if(data==....

Comment: Does `success` even trigger? If the response is not a `200 OK`, only `complete` will trigger, not `success`. Firebug has a Network tab. Check that for the response.

Comment: Here is my php file, is a method because I am using MVC -> http://kupaste.com/ver/64167

Comment: The response is 200 OK

Comment: in your ajax request include `dataType:'html'` and then try again.

Comment: I did it, but that did not resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found, using JSON.

In my Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: "login.php",
           data: 'usremail=' + usremail +
                 '&clave=' + clave
           }).done(function(data) {
                            if (data.mensaje == "ok") {
                                document.location = "index.php";
                            } else {
                                $('#dvmsjlogin').html(data.mensaje);
                            }
                        });
```

And in my PHP:

```
if ($auth->authenticate()) {
  $res['mensaje'] = 'ok';
}else{
  $res['mensaje']='error';
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code with `function (responseText)` ;)

```
success: function (responseText) { // Get the result and assign to each case.
        if (responseText == 'ok') {
            document.location = "account/main.php";
        } else {
            alert('Access denied');
        }
    }
});
```