# Checking Login with Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I created a simple login for with just two inputs username and password. Im using ajax to pass the data being this will be used in a mobile app. For some reason, I am having an issue verifying my credentials against whats stored in the db. I am using standard PDO and a very simple ajax formData call.

My form:

```
<form method="post" id="userLoginForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="uName">Username</label>
       <input type="text" name="uName" id="uName" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" 
        data-corners="true" />
   <label for="uPass">Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="uPass" id="uPass" data-theme="a" 
        data-mini="true" data-corners="true" />
       <p></p>
   <center>
       <button type="submit" data-theme="a" data-mini="true">
           <small>LOGIN</small>
       </button>
   </center>
 </form>
```

My ajax POST method in the head of my doc (in the same document as my form):

```
var fd = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
        var username = $("#uName").val();
        var password = $("#uPass").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: false,
            //data: { user: username, pass: password },//
            data: fd,
            url: 'urltomylogincheck/loginChk.php',
            success: function(html){
            if(html==1)    {
                 //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
                sessionStorage.setItem("user",username);
                alert('Wait while we log you in');
                 window.location.href = 'user.html';
            }
            else {
                $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                 $("#add_err").html("<div style='background: red; padding: 
                 2px 5px 5px 5px;color:white;'>
                <small>Wrong username or password</small></div><br/>");
                }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#add_err").html("<img src='img src='assets/img/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...<br/>")
           }
          });
    return false;
        });
    });
```

an my simple PHP check service:

```
 session_start();

 $user   = $_POST['uName'];
 $pass   = md5($_POST['uPass']);


 if(isset($user)) 
  {
    $check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiletbl 
       WHERE user = :UserName and pass = :Password");
    $check->bindParam(':UserName', $user);
    $check->bindParam(':Password', $pass);

    $check->execute();

    $count = $check->rowCount();
    $row  = $check-> fetch();

    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['user'];
       ///header("location: home.html");
    }
    else {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
        $errflag = true;
        session_write_close();
        ///header("location: about.html");
        exit();
    }

    $check = null;
```

When i test the login, it simply get a response from loginCheck.php that says:

> [image]

I've created a login before with no problem using mysqli but for some reason, Im starting to believe something in my ajax is causing the stink. Any help with this would be great.

Comment: if($count==1)
    { does not print 1. so html variable in success function is empty

Comment: Any errors in the PHP Error log? Presumably $conn is declared somewhere prior to the code shared?

Comment: Print_r your session to see if the variable is being set. There is clearly PHP missing from you page, as we can't see the  return.

Comment: You're not echoing a response to the AJAX in your PHP code.

Comment: May be this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269281/login-with-ajax-jquery

Comment: yes... i echo'd - "connected..." to make sure my connection worked and it worked fine. My question about printing the $_SESSION is how do you see it once ajax has passed the data to php?